# Simple algorithm for approximation image contour for line segment

Tags: c#, image-processing, contour, emgucv

The image contour is a array points. I need to approach two points on each side to create four line segments.

[Image contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhEOX.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So what was the problem when you tried to implement this? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. It is expected that you've done some research and attempted to solve the problem on your own. For more information, take the [tour] and read the [ask] page. Then edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach.

Find the convex hull of these points.

Then find the two vertices which are the furthest apart. This gives a first diagonal.

Then find the two other vertices that are the farthest from the first diagonal. This gives a second diagonal.

Now you can just use the quadrilateral formed by these four vertices.

If you want a tighter fit, you can consider the subsets of points in the four quadrants defined by the diagonals, and compute best fit lines, for example by least squares.

[image]

Comment: This approach using hull convex really is simple and efficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another one using convex hull too :

Find convex hull of points set

Compute convex hull arc length.

And finally compute an approximate polynomial contour with error equals to 10% of arc length (if more than 4 points increase percent of error)

```
CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(vec, vecApprox, 0.1 * arcLength, true);
```

This give good results and commonly used for licence plate détection wich is the same problem.